# mobile phone's carrier information

Tags: php

We need to test the sms text notifications thru our project which is implemented in PHP. We have used the phone number combine with the carrier gateway. For example 7-11 Speakout (USA GSM) has a gateway @cingularme.com, so while send sms we are combining the number with the gateway as 9860112354@@cingularme.com and sending this thru PHP's mail function.

Now wee need to test this on our mobile phones. However we are unabel to find the carrier gateway list for the same (Nokia 6300). Please advise.

Comment: Nokia isn't a carrier, it's a manufacturer. At best it's the Operating System. Do you want the way to get the user's carrier, or the email address gateway for various carriers?

Comment: We have Vodafone & Airtel cards but we don't know the gateway carriers that used in pune. Could you please help us so that we can test the sms functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for a list of carrier email to SMS addresses? Such as #@tmomail.net?

If so, here's an exhaustive list:

http://www.mutube.com/projects/open-email-to-sms/gateway-list/

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem also. The carrier gateway list, as posted out by another answer - is irrelevant to the device, but instead has to due with it's service provider. What you will need to do, is find the carrier - and then fetch it's email to SMS address, to build the e-mail address to send your message to. Such a list can be found on wikipedia.

To get the carrier and service provider of the cellular device, here is a simple function that will provide the cellphone's carrier name when provided with a celluar number:

```
<?php                               
// leave this blank - we may never implement an authentication key
$smsarc_API_key = ''; 

// enter the user's 10 digit cell phone number. 
// example format: $smsarc_to = '5556667777';
$smsarc_number = '5192097991'; 

// lookup carrier
$ch = curl_init();  curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.smsarc.com/api-carrier-lookup.php?sa_number='.$smsarc_number);   $AskApache_result = curl_exec ($ch);        $smsarc_message_status =  $AskApache_result; curl_close($ch);

// print the carrier lookup results
echo $smsarc_carrier;
?>
```

Developer API from their site:
http://www.smsarc.com/free-php-cell-phone-carrier-lookup/